# PreferenceActivity Customization

Tags: android, android-preferences

Can we customize the PreferenceActivity's layout screen.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending the `*Preference` classes.

You can check smspopup's [src code](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSMSPopup%2Fsrc%2Fnet%2Feverythingandroid%2Fsmspopup%2Fpreferences). There are quite a lot of preference customizations there.

Comment: I am asking about the first screen itself. Default screen is coming for the PreferencesActivity. We have to include any preference inside <PreferenceScreen> tag only in the xml and  preferenceScreen is final . so how we can change the screen look and feel.